# Effects are still subscribed to when changing feature module in NgRx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a project with multiple lazy-loaded features. In one of them, I have an effect that listens to actions of type `routerNavigatedAction` from `@ngrx/router-store`, like this:

```
changeRoute$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(routerNavigatedAction),
        mergeMap(action => 
            this.http.get("/some/url").pipe(map(x => myFeatureActions.loadSuccess(x)))
        )));
```

But when I go to another part of the website, loading another feature (ie a module loaded under a certain route), I can still see these calls being made. So the observable inside the `changeRoute$` effect is not being unsubscribed.

Is this the intended behaviour? Can I free the resource somehow?

Comment: What is the problem here? The fact that the calls are still being made or you want to free the resources?

Comment: @ukn Well, both. The fact that the resource isn't freed (ie it's still subscribed on) is the reason why unnecessary http calls are made, and it's unecessary memory and CPU usage (although I guess not too bad). The url is actually uses the params from `action`, so I keep getting 404 in the network tab of the dev tools

Comment: it make sense that it still subscribe since the module has been loaded and sometimes its the behavior you want. If you want to unsubscribe this effect, you need to disptach a cancel action and make the effect emit an empty observable. Otherwise you can just filter(I have no idea what would be the condition because I dont know what it is you are trying to do) before the mergeMap which would stop the http call to be made